# Call a function from a JS function

Tags: javascript, function

There is code in listing 1 and there is a function in listing 2. Both fragments are in the same file and fragment of listing 1 well fulfills other functions as soon as it comes to function from listing 2 will not work. If you copy the whole fragment into a function, everything works, but you want to make it easier. How can I call part of the code in a function?

listing 1

```js
   

 var get_number = obj.Price.Itog;
var get_сurrency = obj.Currency.symbol;

function declOfNum(get_number, titles) {
    return titles[(get_number%10==1 && get_number%100!=11) ? 0 : get_number%10>=2 && get_number%10<=4 && (get_number%100<10 || get_number%100>=20) ? 1 : 2]; //v3 
    }
if (get_сurrency == 'грн') {
    var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['грИвна', 'грИвны', 'грИвен']);
}
else if (get_сurrency == 'сом') {
    var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['сом', 'сома', 'сомов']);
}
else if (get_сurrency == 'тг') {
    var final_currency = 'тенгЕ';
}
else {
    var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['рУбль', 'рублЯ', 'рублЕй']);
}
```

listing 2

```js
   

 function GenTextPriceHour(obj)
    {
        var t = '';
        var coeff;

        if (obj.Tariff.tunes.C_PRICE_FACTOR == null) {
            coeff = 1;
        }else {coeff = obj.Tariff.tunes.C_PRICE_FACTOR;
            }

        if(obj)
        {
            if (obj.Price.Discount) {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code,'PriceWithDiscountHour',[Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]) + ' ';
            } else {
                t = t + getText(obj.Language.code,'PriceNoDiscountHour',[Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]) + ' ';
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to execute certain code in multiple places/times. create  a function with that particular code as function body. call the function wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `final_currency` in `GenTextPriceHour`. If you move your if-else logic to a function, `final_currency` won't be available to the `GenTextPriceHour` function.

Instead, define `final_currency` globally, then move your updating code inside a function which will update the global variable, something like this:

```js
   

var get_number = obj.Price.Itog;
var get_сurrency = obj.Currency.symbol;
var final_currency = '';

function declOfNum(get_number, titles) {
    return titles[(get_number%10==1 && get_number%100!=11) ? 0 : get_number%10>=2 && get_number%10<=4 && (get_number%100<10 || get_number%100>=20) ? 1 : 2]; //v3 
    }

function updateFinalCurrency() {
 if (get_сurrency == 'грн') {
        final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['грИвна', 'грИвны', 'грИвен']);
    }
    else if (get_сurrency == 'сом') {
        final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['сом', 'сома', 'сомов']);
    }
    else if (get_сurrency == 'тг') {
        final_currency = 'тенгЕ';
    }
    else {
        final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['рУбль', 'рублЯ', 'рублЕй']);
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing has changed when it comes to the function, it works in half, final_currency does not return its value.

Comment: Are you calling the `updateFinalCurrency` function before using the value of `final_currency`?

Comment: and where it is necessary to call?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you're not calling the `GenTextPriceHour(obj)` function anywhere. Also, you'd need to define the `final_currency` as a GLOBAL variable, out of the if statements, so it can get the value which is passed into it in the if statements and then use it in the `GenTextPriceHour(obj)`.Currently the variable is LOCALLY defined and that way it can't be used outside the function/if statement etc. To do so, in listing number 1 just type:

```
var get_number = obj.Price.Itog;
var get_сurrency = obj.Currency.symbol;
var final_currency = '';

function declOfNum(get_number, titles) {
    return titles[(get_number%10==1 && get_number%100!=11) ? 0 : get_number%10>=2 && get_number%10<=4 && (get_number%100<10 || get_number%100>=20) ? 1 : 2]; //v3 
    }
if (get_сurrency == 'грн') {
    final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['грИвна', 'грИвны', 'грИвен']);
}
else if (get_сurrency == 'сом') {
    final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['сом', 'сома', 'сомов']);
}
else if (get_сurrency == 'тг') {
    final_currency = 'тенгЕ';
}
else {
    final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['рУбль', 'рублЯ', 'рублЕй']);
}
// CALL THE FUNCTION HERE 
GenTextPriceHour(obj)
```

Comment: nothing has changed when it comes to function, nothing comes back. should final_currency be placed in a function?

Comment: No, the `final_currency` should be defined globally, as above, because you give it a value if some parameters are met (the if statements) and also because, if you define the variable inside a function, the scope of that variable will be ONLY within the function, meaning you won't be able to use that variable with that value outside the function. So yea, define it globally. From the second function, `GenTextPriceHour`, only the final_currency doesn't works, or is it the whole function ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, that's the whole function does not work

Comment: that is, even this part of the code is not returned "t = t + getText(obj.Language.code,'PriceNoDiscountHour',[Round(obj.Price.Itog)"